# Create a new row for every occurrence of a line break in a string

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column of cells containing text that includes line breaks, and need to create a new row on a separate sheet for each of these lines. For instance, Cell D3 might contain

Value1 [Line Break] Value2 [Line Break] Value3 [Line Break]

and Cell D4 might contain

Value2 [Line Break] Value4 [Line Break] Value3 [Line Break]

I am trying to create a new row on a separate sheet for each of these values, so cell A1 would contain Value1, cell A2 would contain Value2, A3 Value3, then A4 would contain Value2, A5 Value4, A6 Value3.

The values repeat and the order is important.

I have looked at using TextToColumns and the solution provided here: http://chandoo.org/wp/2011/08/23/split-text-on-new-line-macro/
But I cannot get either of them to work as needed.

I'm not sure how to modify the chandoo solution to work vertically (it just prints Value1 one time for each value in the cell).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: This is what I tried changing the code to:

```
Sub splitText()
'splits Text active cell using ALT+10 char as separator
Dim splitVals As Variant
Dim totalVals As Long

splitVals = Split(ActiveCell.Value, Chr(10))
totalVals = UBound(splitVals)
Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, ActiveCell.Column), Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1 
+ totalVals, ActiveCell.Column)).Value = splitVals

End Sub
```

I changed the +1 and +1+totalVals modifiers from the column to the Row in the second to last line.

Comment: What have you tried to modify that code?  Stack Overflow is not here to do that for you.

Comment: I changed it so that the modifiers on the ActiveColumn in the Range were on the ActiveRow, however I cannot figure out why it only prints the first value rather than each value. The original code prints all values in the cell, just in the next column as opposed to the next row.

Comment: Please put the code into the original post and not the comment

Comment: Try `.....Value = Application.Transpose(splitVals)`

Comment: Once I figure out how to get it to correctly display the data in new rows, I know how to make it populate in the correct cells. I'm just trying to figure out how to get it to display the correct data beneath it for now.

Comment: @A.S.H Just tried that and it displays the first value an extra time now.

Comment: You still need to play around with it: create a new worksheet, do the copy there, etc. But you have a good place to start for now.

Comment: I figured it out actually, your code worked. My mistake.